# Why return can not be executed in `if __name__ == "__main__"` in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a program and I need the program to return a integer say `changed` to remind the controller that there are something changed.But when I want to return this value, I kept receiving this message:

```
 return 1
 SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

I have read some posts online they all said it is the indent problem but I am sure My indent is right because I have tried such a simple program but the failure still exists.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


if __name__ == "__main__":
     return 1
```

here is the error message:

```
runfile('/home/iphyer/untitled1.py', wdir='/home/iphyer')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
 execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/iphyer/untitled1.py", line 9
   return 1
  SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Although my real programe is more complex than this but the structure is the same.

I am confused because if I comment the `return` statement all program can be run without any warning.

It is quit confusing. I guess I can not using `if __name__ == "__main__` for `return` some value?

Thank you!~

Comment: Because `return` has to be in a function. If that does not make sense to you, please read up on functions.

Comment: Where do you expect the value to return to?

Comment: @BrenBarn I am responsible for one part of the code the return value maybe used my another gay. and I should return the value of `changed` .

Comment: @sikisis, then this is a work for another guy let him import your module and call your method like 'getChange' etc

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 OK, I will further read Python's documents. So you mean `return` must in a function, and that's means I should drop `if __name__ == "__main__` and change code in `if __name__ == "__main__` into a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The body of the `if __name__ == "__main__":` executes when the file in question is being run as a standalone program.  In that case, what you may want is `exit()` or `sys.exit()` which allow you to return limited information to the script that invoked this one.  Typically you can either signal success with `exit(0)` or set of possible failures with a non-zero result (limited to 1 - 255).  `return` is for subroutines/function, `exit` is for programs.

Comment: Terrific, I got it. So I should use `exit()` to give out the information.

Comment: @sikisis, it depends on whether the utility you used to run the program gives you access to the return code.  In Python's subprocess module, for example, it's availble as a `returncode` property.

Comment: @sikisis, I have two questions. do programs work simultaneously? Do one program work after another?

Comment: so I can use another Python Script like subprocess deals with the `exit` value. OK, I will ask the the corresponding gay and see what he wants.

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ one after another, one which i do is check whether the webpage content changed and the other one revise the local database.

Comment: Why don't you want to communicate via file system? Write property to the file -> read from the file. What @cdlane writes is perfect truth, but this is a bad design pattern

Answer (score 3):

Because [if statement](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html) isn't a method. You can `return` only from [methods](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html) in Python.

Comment: I think OP wants a C style return and is asking how to achieve this in python

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ I should drop the `if statement` and  change code in `if __name__ == __main__` into a function. No need to return here in main?

Comment: @Alan yeah, I am often confused Python with C.

Comment: Yes. Just create a `function` that will return value. And use it in another 'file' like: `import your_module; your_module.your_function()` this will do thing what you need

Comment: Or see answer of @cdlane if you for some reason decide to abstain of dealing with internal dependence, but with script output

Comment: Thank you, this is the first time I cooperate my code with other gays and I am quit confused by this. Thank you！ I understand it.